# I want to use reflection in Java 17 for all JRE classes. Is there a way to do this easily?

Tags: reflection, java-17

I could assemble a very long list of --add-opens flags, but I was hoping there was a cleaner way to allow reflection to all JRE classes. My code needs to use reflection for many operations, for instance to get the files[] value of a java.util.logging.FileHandler, but there are many cases like this, and I don't have time to extensively test every possible operation to find all the ways that this could break at runtime.

Could somebody either provide 1) a short command line launch param to enable this, or 2) a complete list of --add-opens commands to enable reflection for every JRE class?

Answers telling me not to use reflection are unhelpful and will be downvoted.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what "they" are trying to stop developers from doing. Before Java 17, you could likely have used `--illegal-access=permit`. But as of Java 17, that option no longer does anything (and the run-time acts as if it was set to `deny`). I believe the point is to force developers to be _explicit_ when breaking encapsulation. So, I would assume there is no quick and easy way to open up all modules in the run-time image to reflection, but I could be wrong.

Comment: “*I don't have time to extensively test every possible operation to find all the ways that this could break at runtime.*” That’s an interesting statement considering that Reflection is a synonym for an operation that doesn’t get any help from the compiler but will break at runtime when you’re doing something wrong. Combined with your intention to access internals which could change in every version, even minor updates, how else do you prove the correctness of what you are doing if not by “extensively testing every possible operation to find all the ways that this could break at runtime”?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in a comment, this seems to be exactly what the developers of Java are trying to prevent other developers from doing. More and more, they're forcing developers to be *explicit* when breaking encapsulation. As such, I doubt there is a quick and easy way to open up all modules in the run-time image to reflection.

That said, you can use the `jimage` tool to list all the contents of an image. The output can easily be parsed to associate package names with module names. Meaning you could write a script to build an `--add-opens` argument for every package in the image.

**Warning:** The JVM appears to limit the number of `--add-opens` arguments to 1,000 (one thousand)<sup>1</sup>.

Example of invoking `jimage` (command line):

```
jimage list <JAVA_HOME>/lib/modules
```

Example script (Python):

```py
import os
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# Usage: python script.py <jdk_home> [targets]
#
#     jdk_home - absolute or relative path to a JDK installation
#     targets  - optional comma-separated list of modules as targets for --add-opens (default: ALL-UNNAMED)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jdk_home = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    command = os.path.join(jdk_home, 'bin', 'jimage')
    image = os.path.join(jdk_home, 'lib', 'modules')
    targets = 'ALL-UNNAMED' if len(sys.argv) < 3 else sys.argv[2]

    with Popen([command, 'list', image], text=True, stdout=PIPE) as proc:
        visited_pkgs = set()
        for line in proc.stdout.readlines()[1:]:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) == 0:
                continue
            elif line.startswith('Module: '):
                mod_name = line[len('Module: '):]
            elif line.endswith('.class') and line != 'module-info.class':
                pkg_name = line[:len(line) - len('.class')]
                pkg_name = pkg_name.replace('/', '.')
                pkg_name = pkg_name[0:pkg_name.rindex('.')]
                if pkg_name not in visited_pkgs:
                    visited_pkgs.add(pkg_name)
                    print(f'--add-opens={mod_name}/{pkg_name}={targets}')
```

---

<sup>1. Limiting `--add-opens` arguments to packages in `java.*` modules resulted in 536 arguments. Including packages in `jdk.*` modules resulted in 843 arguments. Additionally including packages in `javafx.*` modules (for those JDKs that include JavaFX) resulted in 1,021 arguments. No attempt was made to limit packages to only those whose module `exports` them.</sup>

Comment: Does the limit apply to `@argsfile` too?

Comment: Yes. I was using `@argfile` when I encountered the limit. The error is: `Property count limit exceeded: jdk.module.addopens, limit=1000
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: Well, when you have opened `java.lang`, it’s not that hard to iterate over all modules and their packages and add the opens relationship at runtime.

Comment: @Holger I didn't know you could add opens at runtime, I thought it had to be a JVM launch arg. Could you provide any reference to how to do this?

Comment: @JesseBarnum see [`addOpens`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Module.html#addOpens(java.lang.String,java.lang.Module)). Actually intended only for modules wanting to grant access they already have to another module, but when you have opened the `java.lang` package to your code per command line option and look into the implementation of the method, you’ll find a way to open all packages of all modules to your code…

Comment: @JesseBarnum Using the `addOpens` approach works. It's easier to implement and might be the best option for you. Just want to point out that I could see such methods getting the same treatment as the fields of e.g., `Field` eventually (if you're not aware, calling `Field.class.getDeclaredFields()` returns an empty array, despite there being fields; i.e., reflection nowadays filters certain code deemed too important to be tampered with that way).

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @Holger and @Slaw for the tips; this class requires java.base/java.lang to be opened for whatever module it exists in, and then it will open all modules to the ALL-UNNAMED module for the class loader.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, NoSuchFieldException {
    final Module unnamedModule = AddAllOpens.class.getClassLoader().getUnnamedModule();
    final Method method = Module.class.getDeclaredMethod( "implAddExportsOrOpens", String.class, Module.class, boolean.class, boolean.class );
    method.setAccessible( true );

    ModuleLayer.boot().modules().forEach( module -> {
        try {
            final Set<String> packages = module.getPackages();
            for( String eachPackage : packages ) {
                method.invoke( module, eachPackage, unnamedModule, true, true );
                log.info( "--add-open " + module.getName() + "/" + eachPackage + "=" + unnamedModule.toString() );
            }
        } catch( IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    } );
}
```