# Is there a way to open all modules to a specific modules?

Tags: java, java-17, java-module, module-path

I have a Java-Swing-Application with a small, self-written application-debugger (let's call it AID) attached. With AID you can execute code, inspect objects and look at the ui-hierarchy inside the application.

When running the app with java 17 or higher, the module-system gives the usual errors like
"`InaccessibleObjectException: ... module java.desktop does not "opens java.swing.border" to unnamed module ...`". I am aware of the "`-add-opens ...`"-argument and already tried it. Unfortunately I would have to open *a lot of* modules/packages for my debugger to work properly because I do not know which packages are accessed.

I would be ok with making AID a standalone-module if that helps with the solution, but is there a way to open up *all* modules/packages to a specific module (like my AID-module)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Maybe [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76733809/2711488) helps which has been opened a few hours after yours.